# Error when uploading Binary to the itunes store using the Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes-store, application-loader

[image]

The above error appears when I'm trying to upload an app onto the app store using the application loader on Xcode. I'm new to apple development, I have uploaded one app before. This app is similar to the previous one just few design changes and a different stream.

if someone can help me figure this out i would be really greatful. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to upload a `.zip` file. Appstore accepts `.ipa` file created using the Xcode archiver.

Just a suggestion: Before submitting app archive, validate it using Xcode. Follow [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/validating_apps.html) to know how to validate archive using Xcode. Fix issue that come up during validation, then submit.

In case you have confusion or are new to app store submission process you can read through this Apple guide: [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

Hope this helps!